# How to convert a sql query to Pandas Dataframe and PySpark Dataframe

Tags: python, sql, pandas, pyspark, databricks

```
SELECT county, state, deaths, cases, count (*) as count 
FROM table 
GROUP BY county, state, deaths, cases 
HAVING count(*)>1
```

I get the below data from the above query through **SQL**. What i want is convert this SQL Query in both

- *Pandas*
- *PySpark*

[image]

Kindly let me know since I am new to both Pandas and PySpark

Note - I don't want to use `spark.sql` instead i want to use `spark.table` to read from the table and do the aforementioned operations.

Answer (score 0):

It will go like this:

```
df = (spark
     .table("table_name")
     .groupBy(["county", "state", "deaths", "cases"]) 
     .agg(F.count("*").alias("count_rows"))
     .filter("count_rows > 1")
     )
```

Also, the project you are working seems similar to what explained here in details. You should have a look - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fsLQRmednFA&list=PLI57HEydB_p7ICY54CyPtaITuanVZLKTr